# How to defeat Alolan Nintales with Guzzlord-GX deck

Tags: pokemon

I play the Pokémon TCG, and this is the deck I run:

3x Guzzlord-GX
4x Talonflame (Steam Seige 96)
1x Bridget
3x Wishful Baton
2x Repel
47x Darkness energy

In theory, this is how the deck should work:

Start with a Talonflame.  I use him to grab a Bridget and Wishful Baton.  I play Bridget to grab the three Guzzlord, then use Talonflame to grab the other Wishful Batons. Next turn, I retreat to a Guzzlord with a Wishful Baton and eat sloppily.  Due to the large number of Darkness energies, I am almost always guaranteed 4 or 5 dark energies, allowing me to do 180 damage or 100 with two extra prize cards on turn three.  When he is KOed, his wishful baton lets me give his energies to a different Guzzlord so that it can attack.

If I start with a Guzzlord, I eat sloppily turn one and then I can KO nearly any other Pokemon turn two.

I have one main problem with the deck.  My opponents will send out an Alolan Nintales or Hoopa, stopping me from hurting them.  The Repels help, but it's hard to pull them out if I start with only Guzzlord-GX.  Also, my opponents usually choose some benched GX with 190 HP or more.  What would be the best way to counter this strategy?

Comment: Welcome to the site, you may want to try focusing down your questions into one single specific question to make it a bit more answerable. So instead of "How can I make my deck better?" try "I have been struggling with Strategy X, how can I mitigate that?" or "My deck is weak in area Y, how can I mitigate that?"